# dotnet publish - set outputpath in csproj

Tags: .net-core, csproj

I want to know if their is any tag to set the output path of the `dotnet publish` within the .csproj-file.
I know I can use something along the lines of `publish "someproject.csproj" --output "..\mypubfolder"` from the command line. But I want to specify a (default) publish folder within the .csproj-file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set the `PublishDir` property which is used for the `Publish` target:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PublishDir>..\mypubfolder</PublishDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: That it :-)
Everything are 'path's; so I've tried all kinds of combination like PublishPath; PublishOutputPath etc.